# un select dinamico

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

la BD "depositos"

```
'id', 'cantidad', 'num_autorizacion', 'fecha', 'asesor', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'encontrado', 'contrato_id'
```

en el controlador

```
$depositos = Deposito::orderBy('fecha')
        ->whereIn('encontrado', ['no'])
        ->lists('num_autorizacion','id');

return view('payments.paid', ['depositos' => $depositos]);
```

en la vista payments.paid

```
{!! Form::select('autorizacion', $depositos, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

en la vista veo el listado de todos los "num_autorizacion" y cuando selecciono uno, ya me lo vincula con el id y puedo hacer operaciones. en esa parte todo bien. pero hay una forma que el listado del select me muestre "num_autorizacion" + "cantidad".

ejemplo tengo en la BD

```
1:$500:0001
2:$400:0002
3:$650:0003
```

actualmente me muestra

```
"0001"
"0002"
"0003"
```

pero me gustaría que el listado me saliera

```
"0001 - $500"
"0002 - $400"
"0003 - $650"
```

se me entiende? saludos.-

Comment: deberia ser asi? `'autorizacion','cantidad',  $depositos, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`

Comment: no me funciona me sale `array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba cambiar en tu controlador: 
 la consulta asi:

```
$depositos = Deposito::select('id', DB::raw('CONCAT(num_autorizado, " - ", cantidad) AS num_cant') )
    ->orderBy('fecha')
    ->whereIn('encontrado', ['no'])
    ->lists('num_cant','id');
```

y la vista asi:

```
{!! Form::select('num_cant', $depositos, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: me sale `ErrorException in Grammar.php line 58:
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: Diria que es un error totalmente ajeno a los cambios que yo te he propuesto. La llamada a `strtolower` no aparece en ninguna parte de mi script. Te recomiendo que revises el archivo `Grammar.php` en la linea 58 y le pases algo a la funcion `strtolower`.

Comment: si era mi error, no tenia puesto el `use DB;
use App\Quotation;` y la estaba llamando directamente. muchas gracias por la ayuda !!